# how can i call a template function of xsl when drop down is selected

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xslt

I am trying to call a template function in the XSl code when the user selects an option in the dropdown

```
<xsl:element name="select">
<xsl:attribute name="id">
<xsl:value-of select="$l" />
</xsl:attribute>

<xsl:attribute name="onchange">
<xsl:value-of select="TEMPLATE SHOULD BE CALLED HERE"/>
</xsl:attribute>

    <option value="1">Select</option>
    <option value="2">Daily</option>
    <option value="3">Weekly</option>
    <option value="4">Monthly</option>
    <option value="5">RunOnStartup</option>
```

can anyone tell me the syntax of calling the template.

Answer (score 1):

With XSLT 1.0 as implemented in browsers, the XSLT stylesheet generates HTML, and all event handling must be done in Javascript code that you generate as part of the HTML. If you want to call back to XSLT from that Javascript, you will have to use the transformation API to initiate a new transformation.

This changes if you use XSLT 2.0 as implemented in Saxon-CE. A Saxon-CE stylesheet can include code that responds to user events. You don't need to generate an "onchange" attribute for the select element. You just have to write a template rule like this:

```
<xsl:template match="select" mode="ixsl:onchange">
  ... code goes here ...
</xsl:template>
```

and the template will automatically execute when the "onchange" event occurs on the "select" element in the HTML.

More info (and examples) of Saxon-CE can be found here:

http://www.saxonica.com/ce/download.xml

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of the xsl:template element can be found here: http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_template.asp

```
<xsl:template
name="name"
match="pattern"
mode="mode"
priority="number">

  <!-- Content:(<xsl:param>*,template) -->

</xsl:template>
```

---

```
name:   name    Optional. Specifies a name for the template.
Note: If this attribute is omitted there must be a match attribute

match   pattern Optional. The match pattern for the template.
Note: If this attribute is omitted there must be a name attribute

mode:   mode    Optional. Specifies a mode for this template
priority    number  Optional. A number which indicates the numeric priority of the template
```